How to convert .NET DateTime to kafka Timestamp & Date types
I need to convert .NET DateTime fields to the corresponding Kafka Java types as declared on the Java library before producing messages to Kafka.
How to convert a .NET DateTime to Kafka Timestamp & Date?
I have the following two cases from a kafka schema:
{
   "type": "int64",
   "optional": true,
   "name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp",
   "version": 1,
   "field": "INSERTION_DATE"
},
{
   "type": "int32",
   "optional": true,
   "name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Date",
   "version": 1,
   "field": "BIRTH_DATE"
},

Using Confluent.Kafka you can use the following to convert a DateTime to UnixTimestamp, I am guessing this covers the first case for INSERTION_DATE. What about the BIRTH_DATE field?
Timestamp.DateTimeToUnixTimestampMs(dateTime);

The Kafka C# model to be pushed apparently should contain the following properties:
public class KafkaModel 
{
   public long? INSERTION_DATE { get; set; }
   public int? BIRTH_DATE{ get; set; }
}

The Java library converts a Date to an int like this:
    /**
     * Convert a value from its logical format (Date) to it's encoded format.
     * @param value the logical value
     * @return the encoded value
     */
    public static int fromLogical(Schema schema, java.util.Date value) {
        if (!(LOGICAL_NAME.equals(schema.name())))
            throw new DataException("Requested conversion of Date object but the schema does not match.");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(UTC);
        calendar.setTime(value);
        if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) != 0 || calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) != 0 ||
                calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) != 0 || calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) != 0) {
            throw new DataException("Kafka Connect Date type should not have any time fields set to non-zero values.");
        }
        long unixMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        return (int) (unixMillis / MILLIS_PER_DAY);
    }

What's the equivalent for .NET in C# ?
I tried the following for the BIRTH_DATE field but I am not sure if this is correct. It should be the fromLogical equivalent.
public int? EncodedDate(DateTime? date)
{
   if (!date.HasValue)
   {
      return null;
   }

   var unixMillis = DateTimeToUnixTimestampMs(date);

   return (int)(unixMillis / MILLIS_PER_DAY);
}


Use DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds or DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds. Unix timestamps are UTC and unless DateTime.Kind is UTC, you have no idea what a DateTime's offset is.

If you're absolutely certain date is UTC, you can also use (long)date.Subtract(DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds. Birth dates don't have a time component, so a better type for Birth_Date would be DateOnly. In this case, you can get a DateTimeOffset with the DateTimeOffset(DateOnly,TimeOnly,TimeSpan) constructor.

Oof! That Kafka Java library uses java.util.Date, a class with bad design problems that has been outdated since it was supplanted by java,time, the modern Java date and time API, 10 years ago. Doesn’t Kafka offer support for java.time?!
